# Expression type 'DataRequest' is ambiguous without more context Swift 3

Tags: swift3, alamofire

I am newbie and I have an error that I don't know how to fix, so I would appreciate all the helps. I am migrating from swift 2 to swift 3 and I get this error:

> Expression type 'DataRequest' is ambiguous without more context

Here is my code:

```
 static func renewToken(_ onSuccess: @escaping (JSON) -> Void, onFailure: @escaping (NSError) -> Void) {

    let token = DataManager.token?.token
    let header = ["Authorization": "Bearer "+token!]

    Alamofire.request("\(BASE_URL)\(RENEWTOKEN_PATH)", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: .JSONEncoding.default, headers: header)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result{
            case .Success(let jsonObj):
                onSuccess(JSON(jsonObj))


            case .Failure(let error):
                onFailure(error)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question *is ambiguous without more context*. Please show the declaration of `DataRequest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is misleading you need to make 3 changes with your code.

1. With encoding its not `.JSONEncoding.default` but simply `JSONEncoding.default`
2. With `Alamofire 4.*` and `Swift 3.*` case `.Success` and `.Failure` of Result `enum` is now write in lowercase like `.success` and `.failure`.
3. From Swift 3 use `Error` instead of `NSError`.

So whole code goes like this.

```
static func renewToken(_ onSuccess: @escaping (JSON) -> Void, onFailure: @escaping (Error) -> Void) {

    let token = ""
    let header = ["Authorization": "Bearer "+token]

    Alamofire.request("", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result{
            case .success(let jsonObj):
                onSuccess(JSON(jsonObj))


            case .failure(let error):
                onFailure(error)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much! The . was the problem! Have a good day!